# unwanted rewriting of the icon attribute in polymer-ui-icon during pub transform (probably polymer)

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart2js

ui-scafold from  polymer-ui-elements.  One of the elements I use is the polymer-ui-icon-button.  I can set which icon to use from a selection of options, like 'refresh', which uses the icon from a large image at a particular position in that image.  Standard CSS stuff.  One example is

```dart
<polymer-ui-icon-button tool icon="refresh" on-click="{{refresh}}"></polymer-ui-icon-button>
```

and when used in Dartium, works perfectly.  However, when I serve this through

pub serve

it gets rewritten to be

```dart
<polymer-ui-icon-button tool icon="packages/gcanvas/elements/refresh" on-click="{{refresh}}"></polymer-ui-icon-button>
```

by one of the transformers, maybe polymer, (I assume), but this means when it looks up this string in the icon list, none of them match, so I get a blank icon.  I managed to overcome this with

```dart
<polymer-ui-icon-button tool icon="{{refreshIcon}}" on-click="{{refresh}}"></polymer-ui-icon-button>
```

with

```dart
var refreshIcon = 'refresh'
```

but I can't do this easily to

```dart
<polymer-ui-icon-button icon="menu" hidden?="{{hideMenuButton}}" on-click="{{menuActionTap}}" active="{{menuActive}}"></polymer-ui-icon-button>
```

which is part of the polymer-ui-scafold element.

Is there a way to tell the transformer to not rewrite this attribute. and/or should I create a bug report?

Comment: This is not dart2js, but probably the polymer transformer that rewrites the URL.

Comment: Thanks, even so, it's undesired behaviour.  You might have figured I was guessing there.  I'll alter the question to reflect this though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is this bug https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=17914

My workaround was to move the image *after deployment* to the place where the browser is looking for it.

I think a few additional stars on this bug might help ;-)

Comment: My solution works too, but not for scaffold.  Fortunately I don't need the menu icon, since I have no need for that functionality, so I use polymer-ui-scafold3.  Thanks, I stared the issue.